# Jar file gets corrupted when sent over socket

Tags: java, sockets, jar, bukkit

I'm trying to send a jar file over a socket to a server.
Now everything seems to be working fine but on the other side of the socket, the jar is corrupted. The files have on both sides of the socket the same length. But when I try to use the file in bukkit, the file is corrupted.

The client code:

```
public class Main {
private Socket connection;
private ObjectOutputStream outStream;
private static String serverAddress = ""; // the ip address
static File fileLoc = new File("C:\\Users\\Tom\\Documents\\Qubeproject\\server\\plugins");
static String fileName = "\\WorldEdit.jar";
static File file ;
static InputStream IS;
static OutputStream OS;
static byte[] msgByte = new byte[1024];


public static void main(String[] arg0){
    p("Starting this shit up");
    file = new File(fileLoc + fileName) ; 

    try {
        Socket connection = connection();
        IS = connection.getInputStream();
        OS = connection.getOutputStream();

        OS.write(msg("LOL"));
        //Authenciation


        IS.read(msgByte);
        if(new String(msgByte).trim().equals("OK")){
            p("OK");



            OS.write(msg(fileName));
            //sending fileName


            IS.read(msgByte);
            p(new String(msgByte).trim());
            //confirmation



            OS.write(msg("l:" + (file.length())));



            byte[] fileByte = new byte[(int)(file.length())];

            FileInputStream jis = new FileInputStream(file);
            int count = 0;
            while((count = jis.read(fileByte))>0){

            OS.write(fileByte,0,count);
            OS.flush();
            }

            OS.flush();

            setByteZero(msgByte);

            IS.read(msgByte);
            p(new String(msgByte).trim());
            //confirmation

        }else{
            p("Authenciation failed");
        }







    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
    private static void p (String s){
    System.out.println(s);
}
    private static byte[] msg(String s){
        return s.getBytes();
    }

    private static Socket connection() throws IOException{
        Socket socket = new Socket();
        InetAddress ip =  InetAddress.getByName(serverAddress);
        InetSocketAddress address = new InetSocketAddress(ip,6969);
        socket.connect(address,6969);
        return socket;
    }

    private static byte[] setByteZero(byte[] workByte) {
        for(int i=0;i < workByte.length;i++){
            workByte[i] = 0;
        }
        return workByte;

    }
```

the server code in bukkit

```
public class Checkup  implements Runnable{
Server serverB;
ServerSocket server;
Socket client;
InputStream IS;
OutputStream OS;
static File destination;
byte[] msgByte = new byte[1024];
String filename;
long length;



Checkup (Server serverm){
    serverB = serverm;
}




@Override
public void run() {

    try{
        server = new ServerSocket(6969);
    }catch(Exception e){
    }
    try{
    while(true){
            client = server.accept();


            IS = client.getInputStream();
            OS = client.getOutputStream();

            IS.read(msgByte);


            if(msg(msgByte).equals("LOL")){
                OS.write(msg("OK"));

                IS.read(msgByte);

                filename = msg(msgByte);


                OS.write(msg("Q received name :" + filename));

                OS.flush();

                setByteZero(msgByte);

                IS.read(msgByte);

                length = Integer.parseInt(new String(msgByte).trim().replace("l:", ""));


                OS.write(msg("Q received length :" + length));

                byte[] fileByte = new byte[(int)length];


                destination = new File("C:\\Users\\Quentin\\Desktop\\DE server\\plugins" + filename);

                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(destination);

                int count = 0;



                while((count =IS.read(fileByte))>0 ){



                fos.write(fileByte);
                fos.flush();

                }
                fos.flush();
                fos.close();

                OS.write(msg("Q received the jar!Bye"));
                client.close();



            }






    }       

    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        try {
            serverB.reload();
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

finally{

    }}




private String msg(byte[] strByte){
    return new String(strByte).trim();
}

private static byte[] msg(String s){
    return s.getBytes();
}


private static byte[] setByteZero(byte[] workByte) {
    for(int i=0;i < workByte.length;i++){
        workByte[i] = 0;
    }
    return workByte;

}
```

Comment: You're ignoring the return value of `InputStream.read` everywhere. Don't do that.

Comment: Does this have anything to do with the corrupted file? Because with the fileByte I think I'm not ignoring the return value, as I'm using the count =IS.read(fileByte) .

Comment: Look at *every call* to `IS.read(msgByte)` which ignores the result. Whether or not this is the problem you're looking at now, it's a *big* problem in general. Additionally, you should really check what the differences in the file are - first take an MD5 hash or some other checksum of the file that's being sent and received. It may be that the problem is completely different. There are various other issues with this code to be honest, but it's worth tackling them one at a time...

Comment: Also `flush` the stream after sending from your client to the server (eg. after `OS.write(msg("LOL"));` or `OS.write(msg(fileName));`). Otherwise you might end up hanging because the buffer is not flushed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Jon pointed you to the problem, here it is spelled out and formatted.....

The following code half-ignores the count (and the count is legal to be 0 too):

```
          while((count =IS.read(fileByte))>0 ){
            fos.write(fileByte);
            fos.flush();
          }
          fos.flush();
          fos.close();
```

and should be written as:

```
          while((count =IS.read(fileByte))>=0 ){
            fos.write(fileByte, 0, count);
          }
          fos.flush();
          fos.close();
```